# What's the opposite of a function?

Tags: functions

Functions are mapping from a preimage domain A to image codomain B. Each element in A must map to exactly one element in B.

What do you call a rule that doesn't map an element in A to exactly one element in B, but may map it to multiple elements in B? What would such a mapping or rule be called? "A relation that's not a function" sounds kind of clunky.

Comment: A   $relation$   refer wikipedia

Comment: But relations could be functions, right?

Comment: what do you call a relation that's not a function?

Comment: We call them relation, and not every relation is a function.

Comment: So you call relations that are not functions just relations? I thought relations and functions aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: they are not mutually exclusive, The set of all functions is a subset of the set of all relations - a function is a relation where the first value of every tuple is unique through the set.

Comment: Although a function is a relation, I think that when one speaks of a specific relation it is to some degree implied that it is a relation that is not a function. Otherwise, one would have called it a function. However, when one speaks of relations *in general* then there is no such implication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) It is perhaps worth noting that e.g. Hardy in his classic *A Course of Pure Mathematics*, talking of the case where $y$ is a function of $x$, writes that the principle "to each value of *x* ... corresponds one and only one value of *y*" is "by no means involved in the general idea of a function". Hardy, then, allows many-valued functions as genuine functions. Some modern writers on complex analysis still talk that way.

(2) Tim Gowers writes interestingly on what he calls multifunctions (i.e. many-valued functions) here, http://gowers.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/why-arent-all-functions-well-defined/

(3) There's nothing logically unmanageable about the idea of functions taking plural values -- see e.g. the treatment in Oliver and Smiley, *Plural Logic*.

Comment: Multifunctions sounds like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are multifunctions basically reverse surjections?

Comment: I feel like this answer says "you *can* define function to mean a potentially-multivalued thing" and it's a pretty strange omission to not mention that most people *don't*.

Comment: @BenMillwood I was assuming, perhaps wrongly, that the OP was starting from the standard functions-are-at-most-single-valued position, and because he was assuming it, that's why he was asking about multivalued whatnots. So that's what I didn't think I had to say the standard terminology is indeed standard. But yes, I was just noting the possibility of (sensibly) deviating from it.

Answer (score 2):

A function is a functional relation so a "non-functional relation" would be a relation that is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Related to this is the idea of a "partial function", for which there can be elements in $A$ for which the function is not defined. This is, of course, not a function, but has come up on this forum before. The restriction of a partial function to any subset of $A$ on which the function *is* defined produces an honest-to-goodness function.

Comment: Not contradicting you, just thought I'd add that (similar to what @Emin said in his/her answer), sometimes partial functions are viewed/modeled/whatever as (total) functions, with the codomain augmented with a distinct value "$\bot$". This value can be interpreted as "undefined" and all undefined values in the domain are mapped to $\bot$.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics we give name to things or concepts that have 'beautiful' properties. For the set of relations, we study a special class of them, which we call functions. That's so because of its properties. The other relations that are not functions are not so interested for studying, and that's why they do not have a special name.

However, there is an other notion of a 'functions' that is not a real functions, because they do not fulfill the random conditions of a function. I'm talking about the SET VALUED FUNCTIONS. A set valued function is called a mapping that maps a point of a domain to a subset of a given set. But this kind of function can bee seen as a function as well, where the range of a function is the set of all subsets of a given set.

Example: Let A={0,1}, B={a,b,c} and f(0)=a, f(1)={b,c}. Than $f:A \to B$ is not a function, but $f:A\to P(B)$ is a function!

Comment: Non-functional relations are often very interesting!

Comment: They may be interesting for some cases, but they are not compared to functions.